# Clarification needed to avoid recursion in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

After closed the application when I successfully retrieve the data from it, It opens recursively and I can't close it. Please clarify why this is happening.

```
Sub macro()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long
    Dim sathish As String

    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim eRow As Long

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With appIE
        appIE.Visible = False
        appIE.navigate "website"

        Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        appIE.Visible = True
        appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = ""
        appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = ""
        appIE.document.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click

        Number = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Number = 10

        For Y = 1 To Number
            sathish = Cells(Y, 1).Value
            appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click
            appIE.document.getElementById("filter_ReferenceCode").Value = sathish
            appIE.document.getElementById("filter_btnSetFilter").Click
            'Set IE = Nothing
            Set objCollection = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

            For t = 10 To (objCollection.Length - 1)
                For r = 0 To (objCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                    eRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

                    For c = 0 To (objCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(eRow, c + 1) = objCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                    Next c
                Next r

                If t = objCollection.Length - 1 Then
                    Cells(eRow + 1, 1) = ""
                End If
            Next t
        Next Y
    End With
    ' Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you by any chance mean that the sub/function is called again or that VBA itself does re-open?

Comment: yes, vba itself does re-open

Comment: Maybe you have other code responding to when cells are updated? E.g. a worksheet change event. Try putting `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of your module, then `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end. This will disable events while this Sub runs.

Comment: I have tried this code (Application.EnableEvents = False  at top and Application.EnableEvents = True at end) in my project, although, the same error happens again, i.e., the respective application get opens 'n' number of time, manually I'm closing it. Totally, I'm fed up with it!!! I don't know why this happening... Please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: @sathishkumarronnie Are you closing VBA with a sub or just the red 'x' at top right?

Comment: The function itself probably is not doing re-opening. Could you describe how are you calling this macro() sub?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46470246/edit) to include more information, such as the answer to @smartobelix's question.  Why did you comment out `Set IE = Nothing` at the end?  I think you should do `Set appIE = Nothing` just before `End Sub`.  Also, put `Option Explicit` at the very top of your VBA module.  Could you do a screencast showing the problem?